# My Macbook Pro M1 suddenly isn't showing the correct resolutions anymore

Tags: macos, resolution

I've installed Steam, Parallels and OBS on my Macbook Pro M1, OSX Big Sur 11.3.1. I was doing a live, and also used SwitchResX for a moment. Then, after rebooting it, the resolution was suddenly messed up. On Settings > Displays, the resolutions listed are:

```
1600x100
1920x1200
1024x640
1280x800
```

In that order, which makes no sense. Notice the image below, where the largest resolution listed is 1280x800, while the "default" is 1920x1800:

[image]

Which isn't even the right ratio.

In an attempt to solve the issue, I've reinstalled the OS, but nothing changed.

[image]

How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue. Seems like SwitchResX for some reason messed up with the system resolutions. I've updated to the latest beta version of SwitchResX (4.11.1a4), opened SwitchResX Preferences and then, on the menu at the top of the OSX screen, clicked "Display > Restory factory settings". Then after a reboot it was back to normal. Geez

[image]

"Restore factory settings" is greyed out now, but it wasn't before. Clicking on it and rebooting solved the issue.